# Program to identify if a file is not written

Tags: windows

Firstly, I'm not a programmer so please excuse me if my question lacks technical accuracy.

Basically I have a situation where I have a camera recording a timelapse, taking a photograph at predetermined intervals (in this case 60 seconds) and then saving the image to a Dropbox folder.

I regularly monitor the Dropbox folder to ensure the images are being captured, but there have been situations where the camera has failed and I've not been aware for 24hours or so.

Ideally what I am looking for is a small program that can monitor the Dropbox folder and report back (perhaps by email) to say if an image capture has failed.

There are two parameters that I'd need to set; the interval (in this case every 60 seconds) and the period over which the camera is running (in this case 6am - 6pm).

I've managed to find several different programs that will monitor if a file is written to a folder, but not a program to determine if a file has NOT been written.

Just wanted to ask the community if this would be possible and whether anybody would be able to help?

Many thanks in advance for your advice.

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to read the memory addresses and find if there is anything with the extension `.temp`. Other than that, you'd have to be on Linux.

Looping through memory, especially in this day and age with 32GB-64GB  of RAM becoming commonplace, it is highly inefficient to do this.

Essentially, no, I don't believe there is any way to practically do this.